# How to enable single click cell edit in AG-Grid - Angular 2 without SingleClickEdit?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have been trying to edit the ag-grid cells with single click. I have tried using the `SingleClickEdit = true` option in the `GridOptions`. But, still I couldn't able to achieve single click edit. I have used `dragAndDrop` attribute in the grid options too. Does this affect the `SingleClickEdit` option in AG-Grid? Please suggest an alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: it should be `singleClickEdit` not sure if that is a typo in your question or in your code...

Comment: yes, its singleClickEdit. I have used this. but still, its not the solution bro.

Comment: Which type of editing you've implemented? In Cell or Popup?

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, we found that this combination of settings ENABLED single click editing
singleClickEdit: false,
enableGroupEdit: true

Comment: You mean, do I need to provide this combination for Single click edit option to be enabled in the Ag-grid?

Comment: Upon reflection, the above settings made sense for us, since we were overriding the editor with our own.  Hence, turning singleClick to false only worked for our application.  Ignore the comment about enableGroupEdit, it was just clouding the issue.  Bottom line--ag-grid was working fine, and my own code confused me.

Comment: Which type of editing you've implemented? In Cell or Popup?